# D3 treemap: reserve min width and height for the smallest node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

I am new to D3 world and I built my first treemap.

I can't find solution to reserve the smallest node's dimension (certain width and height).

Basically, if you look at my JSfiddle, you will see that the smallest node having the size of 1 can't properly display its label inside because the box/node is to small so the text can't fit.

```
{"name": "label5", "size": 1}
```

Can someone please help how I can reserve/specify the smallest node's size (width and height) so the certain text/label could fit?

Here's my full [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KVTX9/2/):

[image]

Comment: Hey did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

One method that can potentially solve your problem would be to slightly chage lines 21 and 42 in your code so that they look like this:

line 21:

```
.value(function(d) { return d.size + 20; });
```

line 42:

```
    : function(d) { return d.size + 20; };
```

(notice that all I did was add `" + 20"`.

Here you have the modified jsfiddle: [modified example](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/3hRwM/).

Now, depending on your data you may want to do something else, maybe instead of 20 you can calculate lets say 1% of the sum of all values, but this is a basic idea that can be, I hope, your solid starting point.

Hope this helps.

And this is screenshot of modified treemap:

[image: modified treemap]

Comment: It could works, however summing an integer inside the function that calculates the size for each box, means that each box will be larger with that amount. This means that the aspect ratio of the whole treemap could be also the same and the problem won't be resolved.